# Line Chart generation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, charts

Which is the best line chart generation tool. i need to use it in ma web page. I could also be able to save it to image format. It should be able to plot graph based on a timeline such data pertaining to a particular range of time. I got sucked up using Google Chart. Problem with scaling in that. Any things else???

Comment: hey i need to save the chart also.... as an image.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i highly recommend [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) has a great [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart) and awesome [demostrations](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), it is lightweight, purely javascript based, and very powerful and extensible.

Answer (score 0):

We've had good results with http://www.jqplot.com/.